# .htaccess RewriteCond for a specific url path without https

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

there is a problem with the htaccess rewrite on a specified url (service/scripts/) path. I dont like to redirect if the path contains "**service/scripts** and just open the link with http". All other links should redirect to **https**. I m using the Codeigniter Framework. And i have tried the following code TRY1 and TRY2:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|assets|service/*|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://url.info/" 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
# TURN SSL ON 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.info/$1 [R,L]

# TRY 1 
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/service.*
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.url.info/$1 [R=301,L] 
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/service.*
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.info/$1 [R=301,L] 

# TRY 2
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/service/scripts/?.*$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.url.info/$1 [R=301,L] 
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/service/scripts/?.*$ 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.info/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Removes index.php RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 
# If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing 
# make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark) 

</IfModule>
```

Its always redirecting like the and the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/service.* is not triggert or the secound RewriteCond is overriding it...

Please can somebody help me?
Best regards,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Now I used a PHP Redirect in the HTML Head on all pages to solve the Problem.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
if(!headers_sent()) {
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header(sprintf(
        'Location: https://%s%s',
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    ));
    exit();
}
}
```